# R-Pin on 4-Pin battery?

Tags: batteries

I am currently salvaging parts from a husqvarna automower 305 to use in later projects. Among the parts is a variation of this battery: https://www.amazon.de/Green-Werkzeug-Husqvarna-Automower-McCulloch/dp/B07HY1T4WL

[image: image from Amazon]

It has 4 Pins, + and -, a T-Pin which I suppose gives me a tempereature reading, and then there is a pin simply labelled R. I have no idea what this one's supposed to be. Does anyone have any idea what this pin is used for? I got nothing.

Edit/Update: In the "adapter" used to connect the battery to the robot, the pin is designated "h". Maybe that can help identify it.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. If you've got a photo then add it to your post rather than as a link that will die and render your question useless.

Comment: probably a data line ... used for exchanging charging requirements data